# Do I have to order checks from my bank or can I buy them from a local printer?

Tags: united-states, checking-account

Or can I just ask a local printer to print checks? I ordered checks from my bank, but after 60 days, they haven't arrived, so I think I'll just order checks from local printers. What do I need to tell them?

- Bank routing number
- Bank account number
- Check number
- My name.

That's all, right? I'm in Indonesia, and the bank is in the U.S.

Comment: Checks are usually as carefully protected as currency, and so your bank probably wouldn't honor a check that your local printers might make. Depending on the kind of account you have with the bank, the checks will include features as complex as heat-sensitive ink and backgrounds that dissolve in various liquids to prevent check fraud. I would guess that your US bank wouldn't honor checks that came through printed on paper that was different to their normal stock.

Comment: You should be concerned if the checks were printed and shipped but never arrived.

Comment: @THEAO - In the US, we see ads in the Sunday papers all the time for check printing. The printers have the right ink and presumably know what they're doing. If it's a US Bank, no issue for Jim.

Comment: Fair enough... now that you mention it, I do get those things in the mail all the time for Disney character backgrounds, and the like... I stand corrected.

Comment: @THEAO - in fact, you can purchase check stock and either DM ribbons or special toner and print your own checks. All you need to do is conform to ACH standards for check dimensions and the locations (and tolerances) of various fields. My first job was maintaining an ERP that had the ability to print checks, and the company used their own application for its finances, so the validity of my paycheck was predicated on doing a good job setting up those check templates.

Answer (score 3):

If you were in US, you could have the check printed essentially would need to give the Bank routing number [ABA code] and the account number. The check number need to be printed in MICR ink. However as you are outside US not sure about the rules here. It may be advised to get it from Bank.

Comment: Are you sure about those requirements. As I understand it you could hand write a check with your account number on it and it would work as a check. At least the bank would honor it even if the sales clerk didn't.

Comment: @JohnFx: My understanding is that one should have a MICR line printed for the check to be accepted in clearing. One can handwrite a withdrawl instruction and give it to your own bank. Bank will honor it. One cannot give a handwritten instruction a Bank other than the Account holding Bank.

Comment: Here is the definition in UCC Article 3: http://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/3/3-104.html